# LINQ Query only returning one result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to display a list of blog posts, all of which are filed to a specific category by a specific author and can have x number of tags. Here is my database set up:

```
Posts
    PostId
    Title
    PostDate
    Body
    Draft

Categories
    CategoryId
    CategoryName

PostCategories
    PostId
    CategoryId

Authors
    AuthorId
    AuthorName

PostAuthors
    AuthorId
    PostId

Tags
    TagId
    TagName

PostTags
    PostId
    TagId
```

Sample data (commas used to separate database columns):

```
Posts    
-----
1, Test Post #1, 2/5/2015 12:00:00, This is a test post, 0
2, Test Post #2, 2/5/2015 12:00:00, This is another test post, 0

Categories
----------
1 Test Posts

PostCategories
--------------
1, 1
2, 1

Authors
-------
1, Test Author

PostAuthors
-----------
1, 1
2, 1

Tags
----
1, C#
2, ASP.NET MVC
3, LINQ

PostTags
--------
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
```

I used entity framework to create models based on the database tables and created a view model `BlogViewModel`:

```
public class BlogViewModel {
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following LINQ query that is returning one row even though two rows exist:

```
var results = from p in posts
          join pc in postcategories on p.PostId equals pc.PostId
          join c in categories on pc.PostId equals c.CategoryId
          join a in authors on pc.PostId equals a.AuthorId
          join tp in tagposts on p.PostId equals tp.PostId
          join t in tags on tp.TagId equals t.TagId
          group new { t, p, c, a } by tp.PostId into g

          select new BlogViewModel
                    {
                      Post = g.FirstOrDefault().p,
                      Category = g.FirstOrDefault().c,
                      Author = g.FirstOrDefault().a,
                      Tags = g.Select(x=>x.t)
                    };
```

If there is a cleaner way to get all of this data without having all the joins, I would certainly be open to that.

Can someone see why that might be and help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do your two rows have the same post ID? (You're grouping by that...)

Comment: No, they have unique IDs

Comment: It would really help if you'd a) try to simplify it by removing some joins (do you really need 6 tables in order to find the problem?); b) post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, including data.

Comment: As Jon is implying, if you have your navigation properties in place, you shouldn't need all of those messy explicit joins.

Comment: @MattAltepeter One thing that springs to mind, why are you using select FirstOrDefault() ? Why not something like g.Key.p etc ?

Comment: Another thing could be because you are joining on the wrong columns (1) pc.PostId equals c.CategoryId (2) pc.PostId equals a.AuthorId. Those expressions don't make sense. Could be you just got lucky that the only row you got has the same values on those Id fields and the other did not.

Comment: Updated question with more information

Comment: Yeap there you go... look at your post categories, you have and 1 and 2 and yet only have "1" Category. So the other row did not match because of the wrong joined columns. I'm referring to the "Ids" and not the "number of rows", just to clarify it.

Comment: So switching from using `pc.PostId` to `p.PostId` should fix my issue I believe, correct?

Comment: This too: join a in authors on pc.PostId equals a.AuthorId. You need to change them to:join c in categories on pc.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
join pa in PostAuthors on pa.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId and pa.PostId equal p.PostId
join a in authors on pa.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId